# How to export themes and extensions?

Tags: theme, extensions, export

This is my situation:

I have a backup of an old website wich i used.
I'm creating a new website for a new purpose so i don't want to restore the old backup.

What i do want is to use a few extensions and a theme that was used in this website.
The company that created the website for us doesn't exist anymore, but the extensions were paid extensions, and also is the theme i want to use again.

How do i export these extensions and the theme so i can use it in my new website?

Thanks!

Comment: In Magento there is no functionality to export theme and extension

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, you can't.  Slightly longer answer, if you understand the construction of extensions then it's pretty quick and easy to track down all files related to any particular one.  Essentially starting from each extensions `config.xml` you can track down all files related to that extension.  This is because Magento is a configuration rather than convention based framework, so all resources that need to be accessed must be declared and that happens in each `config.xml`.

As for themes you are probably going to have to refer to the original theme archive to know what files exactly it added - many themes also add modules and outside of that there will most likely be a combination of JS, CSS, template files and images, the location of which there is no general rule for finding.